# Yammer JS SDK auth example Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue github.io

Tags: javascript, yammer

I am trying to use the JS SDK Example, however I get an error making the request.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json?_=1409663479660. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://webmutation.github.io' is therefore not allowed access.

I have the https://webmutation.github.io in the Javascript Origins... so I am scratching my head right now about this...

So when I use the example:

```
function login() {
            console.log("Trigger setAuthToken");
            yam.platform.setAuthToken({
                    token: localStorage.getItem(1)
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        console.log("Logged in and got code");
                        displayAuthResult(response.access_token);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Not logged in.");

                    }
                });
        };
```

The response object seems a bit strange to me, since it does not have the authResponse propriety instead it shows up like this:

> **response**: Object access_token: "" perms: "" status: "notConnected"

The other example with the pop-up works. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, so as per this update, 
https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/

I wanted to update the Javascript Origins, but i don't find the option in my app. Any idea?

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have a question yourself that looks like this one, you should wait for an answer or ask your own question with the "Ask Question" button above. and link to this question.

Comment: Well, i intend to say that http://developer.yammer.com/assets/sites/12/2014/04/dev-javascript-origins.png - if someone who finds this option in their web interface, it could solve the issue.